# How to number all lines in a draft?

Tags: line-numbering

I want to have a draft of a document I am writing, with the line numbers aside. I looked at some options like `lineno`, but this way it skips some lines. Is there a simple workaround or another package to do this?

Comment: What kind of lines does it skip?

Comment: @Leonardo Basically anything in a box. Displayed math also causes problems.  See this [this answer here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11367/lineno-numbering-abstracts-lines/11406#11406).

Comment: @endir: Welcome to tex.sx! Does the answer in Alan's link help you?

Comment: @endir: Any update on this? The answer to the question lined by @Alan seems like the best plan to me.

Comment: See also [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13515/how-to-add-paragraph-line-number-in-right-margin/13516#13516) which explains how to use `\internallinenumbers` to number boxes etc.

Comment: @endir @Alan Munn see my post below for pointers how to solve the display math problem.

Answer (score 9):

The [Number every line of pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16010/number-every-line-of-pages/16012#16012) question was very similar to this.

The code I posted [Number every line of pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16010/number-every-line-of-pages/16012#16012), appears to solve this problem and hence the reason for posting this short snippet here. As the code does not box or unbox paragraphs, displayed math can be used.

[image]