# How to add paragraph line number in right margin

Tags: paragraphs, line-numbering

In passages, the line numbers are given on the right side of the paragraph. Like this:
[image]

How could this be implemented in LaTeX?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`lineno`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/lineno/) package is what you are looking for.

As a first approximation to what you want: `\usepackage[modulo,right]{lineno}`. If you want the numbers to start from 1 on every page, add the option `pagewise`. Unfortunately, the package isn't perfect and will go a little... odd when there's a lot of mathmode or figures.

You then need to activate it with `\linenumbers`. Personally, I prefer to use line numbers only in draft mode. So with the `ifdraft` package, I write `\ifdraft{\linenumbers}{}` so that when I'm not compiling drafts, I don't see the ugly numbers.

If you want line numbers *inside* a framed box, for example, you need to put `\internallinenumbers` at the beginning of the environment. I just checked this works with `mdframed`...

Here is some example code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % The lipsum package is only used to generate dummy text
\usepackage[right,modulo]{lineno}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}
  \internallinenumbers
\lipsum[1]
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

The documentation is available [here](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/lineno/ulineno.pdf).

Comment: what if i am using a framed box?

Comment: @umar I don't know. The `listings` package achieves line numbering with framed boxes, but that's for a rather different purpose.

Comment: @umar I found it: `\internallinenumbers`

Comment: somehow \internallinenumbers does not seem to work for me.... how do I do the paragraphing? Where to put the \internallinenumbers

Comment: @umar what are you using to draw frame boxes? It should work if you put it just after the `\begin{...}`

Comment: for frames `\usepackage[style=2]{mdframed}` and `\begin{mdframed}`

Comment: @umar It works for me. Does your document compile? If not, what errors are you getting?

Comment: It compiles but with warnings like `[15] [16]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 473--478` - can you show me your document code?

Comment: @umar see edited answer. Also, there is no `style=2` option for `mdframed`. It accepts 0,1 or 3... Do the numbers look alright? Are you sure this problem is due to line numbering?

Comment: problem solved - I was actually better off with no frame for the lined lines

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [`lineno`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lineno) package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[modulo,right]{lineno}
\begin{document}
\linenumbers
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

**Edit** package options suggested by Seamus.