# Number every line of pages

Tags: line-numbering

When editing documents it is convenient to have all the lines on a page numbered (on the left margin) so that the reviewer can refer to them in his report. How can I achieve this with LaTeX?

Comment: This questions seems to be a duplicate of [How to number all lines in a draft?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11673/2975), which didn't got answered. However, it links to 
[How to add paragraph line number in right margin](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13515/2975) which seems to doing it. Basically use the `lineno` package. However, it might skip some lines. *Edit:* See also [Lineno - numbering abstract's lines.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11367/2975)

Comment: @Martin Scharrer I saw the article, but I am interested in numbering all the lines, i.e. not just the paragraph.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A slightly different approach to that of the faq pointed out by Lockstep.

Firsty, we need to build a box 3em wide to hold the numbers of all the lines. This box will be later positioned at the left margin and unboxed.

```
 \newsavebox{\@linebox}
 \savebox{\@linebox}[3em][t]{\parbox[t]{3em}{%
   \@tempcnta\@ne\relax
   \loop{\underline{\scriptsize\the\@tempcnta}}\\
     \advance\@tempcnta by \@ne\ifnum\@tempcnta<48\repeat}}
```

We use Knuth's loop to generate the line numbers. We can position the box and typeset the line numbers by using thr `\put` command from the LaTeX's `picture` environment (although TikZ afficionados can use TikZ). As we need this box on every page, we use the `fancyhdr` package to achieve this, rather than messing with the output routines. Other possibilities is the `background` package etc.

```
\fancyhead[LO]{%
\begin{picture}(0,0)%
  \put(-18,-25){\usebox{\@linebox}}%
 \end{picture}}
```

You should place the whole code within a conditional to switch between draft and final mode, depending on your class. The full minimal is shown below.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}
\makeatletter

 \newsavebox{\@linebox}
 \savebox{\@linebox}[3em][t]{\parbox[t]{3em}{%
   \@tempcnta\@ne\relax
   \loop{\underline{\scriptsize\the\@tempcnta}}\\
     \advance\@tempcnta by \@ne\ifnum\@tempcnta<48\repeat}}

 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \fancyhead{}
 \fancyfoot{}
 \fancyhead[CO]{\scriptsize How to Count Lines}
 \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\footnotesize\thepage}
%% insert this block within a conditional
 \fancyhead[LE]{\footnotesize\thepage\begin{picture}(0,0)%
      \put(-26,-25){\usebox{\@linebox}}%
      \end{picture}}

 \fancyhead[LO]{%
    \begin{picture}(0,0)%
      \put(-18,-25){\usebox{\@linebox}}%
     \end{picture}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\scriptsize Draft copy}
%% end conditional
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section*{Lorem Ipsum}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: How may I adjust this code so that the number of the first line in a given page is not 1 but the successor of the previous page's last line's number? Or more succinctly, if a page's last line is N how can I ensure that the first line of the next page is going to be N+1?

Comment: You will need to modify the loop macro. Best to do using  expl3. Perhaps try and if you don't succeed post a new question.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides, How do we modify the code so that the line numbering starts  a bit early (i.e. line number 1 in the previous version corresponds to line number 3 in the new version) and the spacing between the line numbers increases a little (but the continuity remains)?

Answer (score 80):

As Martin Scharrer has pointed out -- and to answer the general question once and for all --: Use the [`lineno`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lineno) package. (The package allows to number *every* line, as shown in its documentation.) See [this](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-linenos) entry of the TeX FAQ for possible pitfalls and alternatives.

The following addition to the tex file will cause line numbers to appear (at least in scrbook class using xelatex)

```
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers
```

Comment: A concise description of the available `lineno` options can be found [**here**](https://texblog.org/2012/02/08/adding-line-numbers-to-documents/).

Comment: I think this approach does not number every line. It always skips many lines.