# Add page and line numbers to a pdf

Tags: pdf, page-numbering, line-numbering

Is there any quick script to add page and line numbers to each page of a pdf document?

1. I often enough get articles in pdf to review, with *no page number*. I end up writing them by hand to refer to each page when pointing errors.
2. When referring an error, I end up counting by hand the lines from the beginning or from the end, or copying the context, to precise the location of the error. It would be much more practical to have a standard way to add line numbers to an existing document.

I could manage editing the LaTeX source to obtain this, but not when I receive a pdf. PDF format does not contain lines per se, so identifying them would require to cluster the $y$-coordinates of the letters, and adding those numbers in the margin would require to take the min of the $x$-coordinates and remove a fixed amount from it. Anybody did this script already, or seen another way?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Alright, here's a go at numbering lines in a PDF (or any other image format) without access to the source.

I wrote a little shell script that, using ImageMagick (at least version 6.6.9-4), converts a given PDF into separate raster images for each page, splits these into half pages, shrinks them to a width of one pixel (so takes the horizontal average, basically), turns this into a monochrome image with a given threshold (black=text, white=no text), shrinks every black sequence down to one pixel (=middle of a line), outputs this as a text, pipes it to `sed` to clean it up and remove all the non-text lines and finally writes a `txt` file with the position of each line as 1/1000 of the text height.

`findlines.sh`:

```sh
convert $1.pdf -crop 50x100% png:$1
for f in $1-*; do 
convert $f -flatten -resize 1X1000! -black-threshold 99% -white-threshold 10% -negate -morphology Erode Diamond -morphology Thinning:-1 Skeleton -black-threshold 50% txt:-| sed -e '1d' -e '/#000000/d' -e 's/^[^,]*,//' -e 's/[(]//g' -e 's/:.*//' -e 's/,/ /g' > $f.txt;
done
```

Running the script takes about 1 second for one page, resulting in a number of files: `basename-<number>.txt`, where odd `<numbers>` contain the positions of the left line numbers, and even `<numbers>` those of the right page numbers. These files can then be read by `pgfplotstable` (at least v 1.4) and be used to typeset the line numbers on top of the imported `pdf` file. I defined a command that takes the page number and four line numbers as arguments, where the four line numbers are used to tell the macro at which "raw" line numbers the "real" text lines start and end in the left and right column. By setting `\pgfkeys{print raw line numbers=true}`, the raw line numbers as found by the algorithm are shown in red.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\newif\ifprintrawlinenumbers
\pgfkeys{print raw line numbers/.is if=printrawlinenumbers,
  print raw line numbers=true}
\newcommand{\addlinenumbers}[5]{
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\leftnumber}{(#1-1)*2}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\rightnumber}{(#1-1)*2+1}
  \pgfplotstableread{\pdfname-\leftnumber.txt}\leftlines
  \pgfplotstableread{\pdfname-\rightnumber.txt}\rightlines
  \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny,anchor=east]
  \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=14cm,page=#1]{\pdfname.pdf}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
      \pgfplotstableforeachcolumnelement{[index] 0}\of\leftlines\as\position{
        \ifprintrawlinenumbers
          \node [font=\tiny,red] at (0.04,1-\position/1000)         {\pgfplotstablerow};
        \fi
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\checkexcluded}{
          (\pgfplotstablerow>=#2 && \pgfplotstablerow<=#3) ? 1 : 0)
        }
        \ifnum\checkexcluded=1
          \pgfmathtruncatemacro\linenumber{\pgfplotstablerow-#2+1}
          \node [font=\tiny,align=right,anchor=east] at (0.08,1-\position/1000) {\linenumber};
        \fi
      }
      \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\leftlines}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\rightstart{min((\pgfplotsretval-#2),(#3-#2+1))}
      \pgfplotstableforeachcolumnelement{[index] 0}\of\rightlines\as\position{
        \ifprintrawlinenumbers
          \node [font=\tiny,red,anchor=east] at (1.0,1-\position/1000) {\pgfplotstablerow};
        \fi
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\checkexcluded}{
                  (\pgfplotstablerow>=#4 && \pgfplotstablerow<=#5) ? 1 : 0)
        }
        \ifnum\checkexcluded=1
          \pgfmathtruncatemacro\linenumber{\pgfplotstablerow-#4+\rightstart+1}
          \node [font=\tiny] at (0.96,1-\position/1000) {\linenumber};
        \fi
      }
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\def\pdfname{article}
\addlinenumbers{1}{20}{50}{2}{65}
\pgfkeys{print raw line numbers=false}
\addlinenumbers{2}{0}{69}{0}{64}
\addlinenumbers{3}{19}{47}{21}{48}

\end{document}
```

As a proof of concept, here's the output for the first two pages of an [article from the Environmental Science & Technology Journal](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/es100683t). I think it works really well. I haven't been able to call `findlines.sh` from within LaTeX, though, this step has to be performed manually before compiling the `.tex` file.

[image: first page of a pdf with line numbers]

[image: second page of a pdf with line numbers]

Comment: Holy ImageMagick Batman!

Comment: Jake, that is pretty impressive!

Comment: The result is very impressive! Running it from LaTeX is not an issue: the idea would be to run a script on each conference submission so that the referee can use the line numbers. 
I am no Graphics Magick user and I ran intro problems when trying to run the script myself (Ubuntu 10, GraphicsMagick 1.3.12), first of which being that that the first call to convert just generates "convert: Request did not return an image.".  I will explore this week and comment more later.

Comment: @Jeremy: The script uses ImageMagick, not GraphicsMagick (which doesn't have the `-morphology` operator needed to reduce sequences of consecutive white pixels down to one). Are you sure that you're using GraphicsMagick, though? On my system, I call GraphicsMagick using `gm convert` (instead of just `convert`). What output do you get when you call `convert -version`?

Comment: @jake: I switched to imagemagick via "sudo apt-get install imagemagick" which announced among other things "Removing graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat" (they are quite similar: http://www.linux.com/archive/feed/59223). "convert -version" now yields "Version: ImageMagick 6.6.2-6 2010-12-02 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2010 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP", and the convert lines of the script work as expected.
The sed instruction generates an error "invalid option -- '$'" (GNU sed version 4.2.1). I understand "-e '1d'" removes the first line, but "-$"???

Comment: @Jeremy: Sorry, somehow  part of the script got cut off. I've fixed the code now.

Comment: @jake: thanks: the scripts works as described now. I have some issues with pgftables, but that might be my install, I will come back to you after some more testing (few!)

Comment: @Jeremy: Just for comparison: `\listfiles` shows my `pgfplots` and `TikZ` versions to be `pgfplots.sty 2010/07/14 Version 1.4.1 (git show 1.4.1-1-g64c9e95 )`, `tikz.sty 2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)`.

Comment: That is amazing, Jake. Favoriting this question for this answer alone. +1

Comment: When I tried this it seemed to produce too many line numbers (999 per column).  Any advice on tuning the `findlines.sh` script so that it's more accurate?   Here's the [example PDF](http://metameso.org/~joe/docs/4Previsited.pdf) I used.  (I'm reviewing papers for a conference that uses the same template, this is my submission.)

Comment: @JoeCorneli: The problem occurred because the valid lines didn't end up as "real" black (which the `sed -e '/black/d'` was looking for), but rather as numerical values with transparency (`graya(0,0,0,1)`). I believe this might be due to changes in recent versions of ImageMagic. I've edited the answer to avoid the problem by looking for `#000000` instead. I've tested this on your file using ImageMagick `6.7.7-10`, and it seems to work fine. I'd be grateful if you could let me know whether it works for you.

Comment: @Jake First of all, thank you very much for your solution and keeping updating. I have succeed to repeat most of your work with some adjustments, so the result is promising. However, I have two questions. Firstly, no matter what PDF files are used, only first 3 pages are perfected with line numbers. The rest are either empty with the page number or ignored totally. Secondly, the final PDF is shrank, so the  printed document will be difficult to read.

Comment: @Frank: I can't reproduce the problem that only the first three pages get line numbers. Maybe you're not adding one `\addlinenumbers` command per page? If that's not the problem, it would be good if you could open a new question and provide an example PDF and the version number of your ImageMagick program. About the scaling, I'll try to come up with a way of keeping the PDF at the original size. I'll let you know when I update the answer.

Comment: To appreciate (and implement) this answer I guess you need to have passed a compsci degree with flying colours... ;)

Comment: Question: Does this answer cover "only" line numbers, -- or does it cover page numbering, too?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty: The page numbers are added automatically using this solution, but my answer doesn't cover cases like starting from a number other than 1, or skipping page numbers, for instance.

Comment: @Jake Impressive solution! As Frank suggested in an earlier comment, the final PDF has shrunk (using your script). Did you already find a solution to keep the original size? Also, an empty page is added at the beginning and at the end of the final document (so the original document starts at page number 2). Is that normal?

Comment: Does this still work? I get a only a bunch of errors of the form `line 4: -black-threshold: command not found
convert:  Skeleton @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3339.` and only empty `.txt` files

Comment: @Arne:  It still works for me (ImageMagick version  7.1.1-12). Which version are you using?

Comment: Strange, I also use `Version: ImageMagick 7.1.1-12 Q16-HDRI x86_64 21239`

Comment: Yes this works.

Comment: Nevermind. I did something completely stupid. Now it works. Sorry!

Answer (score 25):

You can do (1) easily with the [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=1-,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}]{<pdffile>}
\end{document}
```

In the example document, I simply passed the pagestyle `plain` to the `pagecommand`, but using the `fancyhdr` package you can make any kind of extra header/footer you like.  To place the page number appropriately you may also need to adjust the margins using the `geometry` package.  For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\lfoot{\textit{My pdf document}}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\begin{document} 
\includepdf[pages=1-,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}}]{<pdffile>}
\end{document}
```

This places a footer containing "*My pdf document*" on the left and the page number on the right. The margin is made very small so that the page number won't likely interfere with the included document.

To make sure the paper size of the output PDF is the same as the included PDF, add the `fitpaper` option to `\includepdf`. From the `pdfpages` manual:

> fitpaper Adjusts the paper size to the one of the inserted document.

See Jake's answer for a very ingenious method of adding line numbers to an existing pdf.

Comment: This indeed adds the page numbers in a very easy way. Thanks! It has problem with margins, but I guess checking the options of pdfpages should give ways to place the page numbers in other places than down center.

Comment: @Jeremy, you can't do this with `pdfpages` directly, (it can only pass a page commend) but instead you do it within the document using, e.g. the `fancyhdr` package, and/or `geometry` (to change the margins.)  I'll update my answer to make this clearer.

Comment: In the case of the second script, can you suggest how one would adjust the position of the page number? There are no obvious adjustable parameters.

Comment: @FaheemMitha This is just using `fancyhdr` to place the page number. So I've put it in the `\rfoot` = right side of the footer, but you could put it in `\cfoot` to centre it, `\lhead` to put it on the left at the top etc.

Comment: If the pdf has only one page(even if it is strange to add page number to one-page pdf), it won't work.

Comment: @warem It works the same with 1 page PDFs.

Comment: @AlanMunn I complied one-page pdf by lualatex and it didn’t work. But it did work for more then one page pdf. So, I am not sure if lualatex mattered. Anyway, I like your solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

If I understand your need to add line numbers to the PDF, you can by using the `lineno` package. It does, however, only add line numbers according to how LaTeX sets up the text, which can be quite different from the source.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \linenumbers
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: Line number example]

Comment: This adds the line numbers in the source LaTeX document. @Jeremy need to add line numbers to an *existing* pdf documemt.

Comment: No, I think the OP wants to add line numbers to an existing PDF.

Comment: @Alan Munn &  @Martin Scharrer: Ahh, of course. I am the king of misunderstanding people!

Comment: Agreed with Alan and Martin (althouh I think the feature would be useful for many other people too!)

Comment: @AlanMunn I get linenumbers in pdf when I convert the latex to pdf. I use overleaf, and have linenumbers in the src editor.

Answer (score 11):

I've encountered the same problems as the OP jeremy, and my version of convert doesn't have morphology as an option.  So, I've had to find another solution.

If one does not care whether the line numbers correspond to actual lines in the text (for example numbering a scanned document in pdf format) but only that there are line numbers going down the side of the page, one can combine pdfpages with "Knuth's loop" described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16010/number-every-line-of-pages) to put a column of numbers down the left side of every page, which is often sufficient for the purpose at hand.

For example, the LaTeX code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[top=0in, bottom=0in, left=0in, right=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}

\makeatletter
 \newsavebox{\@linebox}
 \savebox{\@linebox}[3em][t]{\parbox[t]{3em}{%
   \@tempcnta\@ne\relax
   \loop{\color{Red} \small\the\@tempcnta}\\
     \advance\@tempcnta by \@ne\ifnum\@tempcnta<66\repeat}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\makeatletter

%% IF PAGE NUMBERS ALSO ARE NEEDED, USE \thispagestyle{plain} INSTEAD
\includepdf[pages=1-,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{empty} \hspace{0.5in} \usebox{\@linebox}},fitpaper]{loremipsum.pdf}

%% FOR LINE NUMBERS > 66 INCLUE OPTION openright AND DISCARD FIRST TWO PAGES OF OUTPUT
% \setcounter{page}{-1}  %% FOR LINE NUMBERS > 66 AND PAGESTYLE plain
% \includepdf[pages=1-,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{empty} \hspace{0.5in} \usebox{\@linebox}},fitpaper,openright]{loremipsum.pdf}

\makeatother
\end{document}

%% TO MAKE LOREMIPSUM.PDF
% \documentclass[10pt]{article}
% \usepackage{lipsum}
% \begin{document}
% \section*{Lorem Ipsum}
% \lipsum
% \end{document}
```

produces the output
[image: addlinenumbers.pdf]

To get numbers going all the way down the page, I had to find a workaround described in the LaTeX code.  For numbering greater than 65, the first page's numbers get shifted to a second page (for some unknown reason), so my trick is to insert a blank page with the openright option (resetting the page count as needed) and then remove the first two pages of output later.  Someone better versed in LaTeX might find a more elegant solution, but this seems to work for me.  You can bet that the authors of unnumbered papers are going to get a short lecture on how important it is to provide the reviewer with line (and equation) numbers throughout.

Comment: This might solve the problem for some, but in my case the coordinates (page,line) used in an anonymous review should be understandable by the authors: it won't be the case if the numbers do not correspond to the lines of the document.

Comment: Springer journals seems to do something like this.

Answer (score 7):

You could also consider using PDF annotations to comment the PDF file. You don't need Adobe Acrobat anymore. Adobe Reader X now has support for PDF text and Highlight markup annotations. There are other alternatives like Foxit Reader or PDF X-Change viewer. If you also have the LaTeX source you can use a package like [`pdfcomment`](http://dante.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/pdfcomment.html). It's more flexible and powerful
than what Adobe Reader offers.

[image]

Comment: I am already using pdf annotator to annotate the pdf document, I could indeed write the numbers by hand, but it is faster to count the lines only when I spot a mistake. An automated solution is what is needed!

Answer (score 6):

It can be done very easily for files produces by pdflatex by using the simple Perl script below. Caveats: the PDF file must be of level at most 1.4 (to obtain this, use `\pdfminorversion=4` when compiling it in pdflatex).

You will need to install two Perl packages: `CAM::PDF` and `PDF::API2`. The numbers are aligned at a distance of `$leftmargin` bp units from the left margin of the paper (this value has to be set on line 5 of the script). The names of the input and output PDF files are provided as command line arguments.

Notice that there is another variable `$threshold`: this is the minimal distance between two lines. Indeed, when you typeset, for example, a superscript, then there is small jump in the PDF file which my script considers as a separate line. But by asking for line skips of at least the threshold, these small jumps are not taken into account.

Here is the script:

```
use CAM::PDF;
use PDF::API2;
$file=$ARGV[0];
$newfile=$ARGV[1];
$leftmargin=70;
$threshold=8;
if (-e $file) {

$pdf = CAM::PDF->new($file);

$nbpages=$pdf->numPages();

foreach $i (1 .. $nbpages) {
$page1 = $pdf->getPageContent($i);
@BTS=();
while ($page1 =~ m/^BT\n((.|\n|\r)+?)\nET/gm) {
push @BTS, $1; 
}
foreach $BT (@BTS) {
$x=0; $y=0;
while ($BT =~ m/([0-9.-]+) ([0-9.-]+) Td/g) {
$x=$x + ($1);
$y=$y + ($2);
if ($2 > $threshold or $2 < -$threshold) { push @{"PAGES".$i}, $y; }
}
}
@{"PAGES".$i} = sort { $b <=> $a; } @{"PAGES".$i}; 

$prey=10000000; @X=();
foreach $y (@{"PAGES".$i}) {
if ($prey - $y < $threshold) {}
else { push @X, $y; }
$prey=$y;
}
@{"PAGES".$i}=@X;

}

$pdf = PDF::API2->open($file);

# Add a built-in font to the PDF
$font = $pdf->corefont('Times-Roman');

# Add an external TTF font to the PDF
#    $font = $pdf->ttfont('/path/to/font.ttf');

# Add some text to the page
foreach $i (1 .. $nbpages) {
$page = $pdf->openpage($i);
$j=0;
foreach $y (@{"PAGES".$i}) {
$text = $page->text();
$text->font($font, 10);
$text->fillcolor('blue');
$text->translate($leftmargin, $y);
$text->text($j);
$j++;
}
}

# Save the PDF
$pdf->saveas($newfile);

}
```

Comment: That's a very elegant approach! It's a bit unfortunate that it requires the document to be compiled with `pdflatex` and a special option, though. The chance that a document has been created that way are pretty slim, and if you had access to the source to recompile the document correctly, you might as well just use the `lineno` package as benregn suggests.

Comment: You can always use ps2pdf14 to change the PDF level of your file.

Comment: Ah, that's a useful hint! Do I understand correctly, though, that the files have to be produced by `pdflatex`? I haven't been able to get the script to work with PDFs of journal articles (for example the one linked to in my answer).

Comment: The limitation is on the level of PDF code parsing. I'm only considering the Td operator (as pdflatex always uses solely that one), but there are others. You should uncompress your file and look at what operators are used for moving to the next line, in the ET/BT areas.

Comment: I've had good luck with this script on many files by also grabbing `Tm`.  This is a simple modification, @yannis, would you be opposed to adding it?

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to add them to a **PDF** file, such as for legal documents, these tricks might work for you.

## Add page numbers to a doc

1. fix xref table if necessary with `pdftk test-foo.pdf output test-bar.pdf`
2. `pspdftool 'number(start=1, size=20, x=550 pt, y=10 pt)' test-bar.pdf test-baz.pdf`

These numbers are a little big, but this works great for scanned evidence sections.  I prepare the evidence section as a separate doc and then number it with the correct "start" number to start after the last page of the brief.

`pspdftool` takes font options, but you have to figure out the font name from the name of the font file, not how it appears in a word processor.

## Add evenly-spaced line numbers to a doc

I do this because in a trial court filing, the lines should be numbered with even spaces, even if I use blockquotes with thin spacing.

LibreOffice links the line numbers to specific paragraphs on the page.

I got tired of using awkward text area blocks for blockquotes and linking them across pages.

I just want to write whatever I want in the page with different styles and stamp on the numbers later.

Solution:

1. Format one page with line numbers turned on in your word processor, and nothing else.
2. Export the line numbers page to nums.text.pdf.
3. Vectorize it so the numbers don't show up in text search.  This worked:
   `gs -o temp.ps -dNOCACHE -sDEVICE=pswrite nums.text.pdf`;
   `gs -o nums-outlines.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite temp.ps`
4. Stamp the numbers:
   `pdftk unnumbered-fulldoc.pdf multibackground nums-outlines.pdf output combinedfile.pdf`

Hope this helps.  -Mark

Answer (score 2):

Here, we give a simple answer to this question by using a few latex packages.
For example, the LaTeX code:

```
%% To make "loremipsum.pdf"
% \documentclass[10pt]{article}
% \usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
%  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.33}
% \begin{document}
% \section*{Lorem Ipsum}
% \lipsum
% \end{document}
```

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=0.5cm, right=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[left]{lineno}
\renewcommand\thelinenumber{\bf\scriptsize\color{red}\arabic{linenumber}}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0} % interline spacing

\begin{document}
\newcounter{ctr}
\newcounter{ct}
\setcounter{ct}{1}
\whiledo {\value{ct} < 3} % 2 is the number of the Pdf pages
{
\enlargethispage{3cm}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.1\textwidth}
\internallinenumbers
\begin{runninglinenumbers*}
\setcounter{ctr}{1}
\whiledo {\value{ctr} < 48} % each page contain 32 line
{
$\longleftrightarrow$\
\stepcounter {ctr}%
}
\end{runninglinenumbers*}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.8\textwidth}
\includepdf[pages=\thect,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{empty}}]{loremipsum.pdf}
\end{minipage}
\clearpage
\stepcounter {ct}%
}
\end{document}

`enter code here`

produces the output 
[image]
[image]

Comment: The line numbers and the lines are not aligned, the shift becomes more and more dominant at the end of the page.

Comment: As for Johnson's solution above: This might solve the problem for some, but in my case the coordinates (page,line) used in an anonymous review should be understandable by the authors: it won't be the case if the numbers do not correspond to the lines of the document.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a minor variation on Alan Munn's second answer for adding page numbers to a PDF.

The difference here is that the page numbers are placed in the lower corner of the page. With the `twosided` option, the numbers are placed on the right lower corner on odd pages, and the left lower corner on even pages. The position of the page numbers are adjustable via the `put` parameters. Also, the page numbers are circled, which makes them show up better.

Thanks to David Carlisle for providing the code and explanations.

```
\documentclass[14pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[margin=.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\numcircledtikz[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
    \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1.2pt] (char) {#1};}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\begin{picture}(0,0)\put(-10,30){\numcircledtikz{\thepage}}\end{picture}}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=1-,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}}]{<pdffile>}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I figured out how to add line numbers to an existing pdf.  It doesn't use TeX and it's a little fiddly to get the sizing right, but here goes:

Prepare a file of numbers, from 1 to approximately 32, using Excel or something else.  Somehow make a png file.  You could do this by saving to pdf in Excel and then using an online conversion tool, or by making a screenshot.  Make sure the column of numbers is waay over to the left edge of the page, and size your row heights so that the numbers take up a reasonable amount of space.

Download and install [PDFill](https://www.pdfill.com/index.html).

Choose Item 8, "Add Watermark to Image."  (It will walk you through opening two files.)

Open the pdf whose pages need line numbers.

Open the png file with the column of numbers.

Now you will choose an amplification factor and an offset value.  Here, as an example, is what worked for me:

[image]

Hit "Save as" and save the file.  The new file will probably open up automatically.  (If not, check your settings in PDFill.)

Now count the line numbers on a sample page, and see if you need to adjust the amplification factor.  Rinse and repeat.  Once you've got the right number of lines, play with the offset value until "1" lines up with the first line of your pdf text.  Save a screenshot of the successful values so you can remember next time!