# Adding line numbers to an IEEE Latex document

Tags: line-numbering

I would like to add line numbers to an IEEE paper style.
I have tried using different approaches, however non was successful. For example, when using `\usepackage[switch,columnwise]{lineno}` there will be line numbers missing when I have equations.

I have produced a sample latex file, could anyone help how to add line numbers to this document.

Thanks

```
\documentclass[journal,onecolumn,12pt]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[switch,columnwise]{lineno}
\begin{document}
\linenumbers
\title{\huge LINE NUMBER TEST}
\author{FIRST~LAST,~\IEEEmembership{Member}
\thanks{FIRST LAST, IS WITH INSTITUTE OF TEST (e-mail: TEST@TEST.COM).} }
\markboth{JOURNAL OF TEST}%
{Shell \MakeLowercase{\textit{et al.}}: Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls for Journals}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
This is for testing the appearance of line number. This is for testing the appearance of line number. 
\end{abstract}
\section{Introduction}
\IEEEPARstart{L}{line} number (LN) in draft paper is a good option to locate exactly where you want. It helps you to find specific information in short time. Line number in draft paper is a good option to locate exactly where you want. It helps you to find specific information in short time. Line number in draft paper is a good option to locate exactly where you want. It helps you to find specific information in short time.
\begin{align*}
z_{1}&=x_{1}+y_{1}\\
z_{2}&=x_{2}+y_{2}
\end{align*}
Line number in draft paper is a good option to locate exactly where you want. It helps you to find specific information in short time. Line number in draft paper is a good option to locate exactly where you want. It helps you to find specific information in short time.
\newpage
Line number in draft paper is a good option to locate exactly where you want. It helps you to find specific information in short time. Line number in draft paper is a good option to locate exactly where you want. It helps you to find specific information in short time.
\end{document}
```

Comment: How related to `IEEEtran` is your question? I mean, are you able to add line number to document produced with other classes? Does the `lineno` package works in other cases?

Answer (score 6):

IEEE's `peerreview` option doesn't seem to work with `two-column` option. In which case, the `lineno` package would do the trick.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[switch]{lineno}
...
...

\begin{document}
\linenumbers
...
...
\end{document}
```

The `switch` option prints the line numbers on the left margin of the left column, and on the right margin of the right column.

(Credits for [Mico's post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/410598/77071) for the solution)

Comment: How to make line numbers red? Just like [review, anonymous, screen] for acm templates?

Comment: @K.Symbol, maybe [this link](https://texblog.org/2012/02/08/adding-line-numbers-to-documents) could be of use for you

Answer (score 2):

By simply adding the option `peereview` or `peerreviewca`, you get something that might suits your needs.
According to *How to Use the IEEEtran LATEX Class* (IEEEtran manual),

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal,onecolumn,12pt, peerreview]{IEEEtran}
```

produces :

[image]

A MWE would be:

```
\documentclass[peerreview]{IEEEtran} % The critical option here is peerreview
\usepackage{lineno} % To obtain line numbers
\usepackage{lipsum} % Just for the demo, you can safely remove it.
\begin{document}
\linenumbers % Lineno command, turn on line numbering.
\title{All I Know About Trains}
\author{Thomas}
\maketitle
\lipsum[15]
\begin{equation}
  23 = 12 + 11
 \end{equation}
\lipsum[17]
\end{document}
```

producing:

[image]

Otherwise, you could try [a method to add the line numbers on a pdf file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18760/34551), rather than during compilation.

Comment: But you can see that there are lines (sentences) between 6-7 without line numbers.

Comment: That's because of the `\IEEEPARstart{L}{line}` option. For the equations to be numbered, you should remove the `*` in the `align` environment. I know this is quite unsatisfactory, but that's all you can do with the `peereview` option.

Comment: I don't have problem with the equation numbers. I know that if I remove the "*" the equation number will appear. My question is about line numbers. I would like every line in the page has its own number, starting from line 1 at the top of the page to the last line at the bottom of the page (nearly line 60).

Comment: @sky-light : Ok, I understand your question (but I'm not sure to understand that "line numbers missing when I have equations" in your initial question, then). My answer is: there is an option in  the `IEEEtran` class that partially solves your problem. I don't have any other latex-solution, but knows a solution [to modify the resulting `pdf`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18760/34551). Maybe someone will come out with a better solution.

Comment: This does not work for me (anymore?). I don't see any line numbers using your solution...

Comment: See the updated answer. You need to use the `lineno` package and to activate it.