# Line numbers for 2 columns on the sides

Tags: two-column, lineno

How am I supposed to put line numbers in 2 columns, on the left side for the left one and on the right side for the right one?

I've read a pdf there's on internet but there's nothing, I've tried already with the next commands, but no one works, the line numbers appear always in the left or in the right side, but not both in a single page:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[columnwise]{lineno}
\usepackage[switch]{lineno} 
\usepackage[switch,columnwise]{lineno}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `\usepackage[switch]{lineno}` doesn't do exactly what you say you want to do? Incidentally, do please tell us which document class you use, and also what the `\documentclass` directive looks like.

Comment: @Mico In my language `estrada` means a place, where people sing aloud (scene). It may explain crying in the question. ;-)

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Also in the nick name :)

Comment: I used \documentclass{article} and on the text I changed it on 2 columns and I tried with switch but it changed the line numbers from the left to the right on both columns, but what I want is the line numbers on the left for the left column and on the right for the right column. I used just to check that on [twocolumn] and the result is still the same... and Estrada is my last name and has nothing to do with crying jaja

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you're using a not-too-funky document class, i.e., one which implements the `twocolumn` option in a reasonably robust way, setting the option `switch` while loading `lineno` should achieve exactly what you say you need to achieve.

Do note that the `lineno` package does *not* recognize an option called `columnwise`. You should have been getting error messages when running either `\usepackage[columnwise]{lineno}` or `\usepackage[switch,columnwise]{lineno}`.

Here's an example. Note that the IEEEtran class employs `twocolumn` mode by default.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran} % or any other document class that uses 'twocolumn' mode
\usepackage[switch]{lineno} % default option is 'left'
\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text

\begin{document}
\linenumbers
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I always vote for Mico too. +1. Hi.

Comment: @Mico it seems that this method does not number the lines for equations (in the proof produced by IEEE, equations are also numbered in the page margin) and also causes the author biographies to disappear. Any fixtures?

Comment: @nanjun -  I'm afraid I don't know what you mean by "causes the author biographies to disappear." If you use just `equation` environments for displayed equations and `\[...\]` for unnumbered displayed equations, the user guide of the `lineno` package suggests (a) setting the package option `mathlines` and (b) encasing numbered `equation` environments and unnumbered `\[...\]` displayed equations in `linenomath` environments. The user guide of the package is quite clear that the package's code unforunately doesn't work right with the displayed equation environments of the `amsmath` package.