# "lineno" not compatible with "balance"

Tags: two-column, lineno

In the file with two columns by `twocolumn` options, the last page can't be balanced by `balance` package if `lineno` package works.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum,balance}
\usepackage[switch]{lineno}
\begin{document}    
\twocolumn[

\begin{@twocolumnfalse}
\chapter{the first}
\end{@twocolumnfalse}
]
\linenumbers
\lipsum[1-8]
balabala
\balance
\end{document}
```

produces:

[image]

Obvious, the last page is not balanced. So, how to balance the last page based on `lineno` working.

---

As `pbalance` would work in sometime, but when there are figures with `figure*` parameter, `pbalance` would be very difficult to be adjusted well.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum,pbalance,stfloats,graphicx}
\usepackage[switch]{lineno}

%\shrinkLastPage{2.2in}

\begin{document}    
\twocolumn[

\begin{@twocolumnfalse}
\chapter{the first}
\end{@twocolumnfalse}
]
\linenumbers
\lipsum[1]
\par
\begin{figure*}[b]  
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum[2-8]
balabala
\end{document}
```

produces:

[image]

Comment: [Mittelbach's answer to this other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/583349/119) basically applies here too. For `\balance` to work it needs to install a new output routine; `lineno` also does its numbering by changing the output routine. The two are incompatible. You can see this immediately by thinking about the question of "where should the line number appear?" For `lineno` to decide whether to put the number on the left or on the right, it needs to know whether the text is in the left or the right column. But `balance` needs to set the text first before deciding ...

Comment: @WillieWong So, how to add line numbers outside the margin with balanced? Is there a way to do so?

Comment: ... where to insert the column switch. A key problem being that `lineno` attaches the line numbers as they are set. So you end up with either lack of balancing, or what happens when you try to combine `lineno` and `multicol` (where the line numbers always show up on the same side). //  So the answer is: "they can't work together, unless someone puts in the effort to write some code to make `balance` work with `lineno` explicitly."

Comment: @WillieWong No other packages can do this?

Comment: Well, _one_ way is to do it without any packages: in a "real" document, you can always typeset it first, count the number of lines, and insert an appropriate `\newpage` to force a column switch. I don't know about any "automatic" solutions to this problem.

Comment: (Though this also will require a little additional work if you want the text to be full justified: before the  `\newpage` you need to locally `\setlength\parfillskip{0pt}`, and after the `\newpage` you need to `\noindent`.)

Comment: @WillieWong Okay. I am waiting for a new and full function package to do this.

Comment: Actually, digging CTAN a bit I see a newish package that may work. Let me post an answer.

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks.  I look forward to your professional and comprehensive answer.

Comment: Line numbers are for review. Use them. After review, use balance. Problem solved.

Comment: @user574859 Yes. You reminded me a lot, but it would be more perfect if they can be used together.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try the [`pbalance` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/pbalance). *Caveat: the author states that it is hackish and of beta quality, so it doesn't always work and sometimes the package would just give up; but it at least sort-of works on a test document.*

#### Try 1

We begin by trying to follow the documentation and just loading `pbalance`, this gives us the test document

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum,pbalance}
\usepackage[switch]{lineno}
\begin{document}    
\twocolumn[

\begin{@twocolumnfalse}
\chapter{the first}
\end{@twocolumnfalse}
]
\linenumbers
\lipsum[1-8]
balabala
\end{document}
```

The output goes in the correct direction:

[image]

#### Try 2

The first try *almost worked*, but it looks like we can move another line from the left column to the right. According to the documentation, we can manually adjust this via `\shrinkLastPage`. So let's try eyeballing where the  break should be. After some trial and error, I settled on `4.1in`

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum,pbalance}
\usepackage[switch]{lineno}

\shrinkLastPage{4.1in}

\begin{document}    
\twocolumn[

\begin{@twocolumnfalse}
\chapter{the first}
\end{@twocolumnfalse}
]
\linenumbers
\lipsum[1-8]
balabala
\end{document}
```

And this time it is almost completely balanced.

[image]

### Additional Caveats

Since you used the `book` document class, I am assuming eventually you want to use this to balance the last page of each individual chapter. As it currently stands, the `pbalance` package cannot do that.

However, the trick that it uses can be implemented manually, and may be easier to do than [using `\newpage` as my comment suggested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/688370/lineno-not-compatible-with-balance/688420#comment1707926_688370). Basically: after the *content* of the document has stabilized, compile your document first. Then issue [`\enlargethispage{<len>}`](https://latexref.xyz/_005cenlargethispage.html) where you would've put `\balance` (in the first column of the final page), with a *negative* length that you determine manually to get the two columns to balance. Repeat for each chapter.

Comment: Manually dealing with this is too difficult for me now. I am not so experienced to adjust these in LaTeX. As for your answers, I found another question, so I updated my question. If you have time, may you check that.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I can help more. Looking at the existing packages for balancing two column or multicolumn text, it is apparent that the problem is quite difficult programmatically.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You help me so much!  I don't think it is quite difficult as it should be easier than `tabularray`. It is just not so important and essential that no one has thought deeply about this.