# Adding line numbers without lineno package

Tags: line-numbering, lineno

I've had several persistent issues with the lineno package and journal article templates (e.g., not numbering certain paragraphs).  Is it possible to just add an "unaligned" column of line numbers on the side of the page?

[image]

Comment: This solution works on the PDF itself. [Add page and line numbers to a pdf](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/18760)

Comment: Please try with `vruler.sty` package...

Comment: @AlanMunn Please if I have a PdF file. Is it possible to add numbers to all the lines? Unfortunaletly, this template in this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18760/add-page-and-line-numbers-to-a-pdf does not work.

Comment: @Student "does not work" is a very vague description, and this question is not the place to have a discussion about it. The solution has quite a few components, including a shell script that calls ImageMagick which you need to run on the file before using the LaTeX code. If you've done all that, ask a new question showing exactly what you did and linking to the original question.

Comment: @AlanMunn Thank you very much. Please just how can I add `ImageMagick `?

Comment: @Student https://imagemagick.org/index.php But if you're using Windows, the script in the answer (not ImageMagick itself)  won't work.  If you're using Mac or Linux it should work.

Comment: I'm using windows. The template does not work. I don't kow what should I do. I will be greatfull if you can help me.

Comment: Should I download the software from this link:https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php?

Comment: @Student Yes, you can download it from there. But I know nothing about Windows. And learning how to translate a `bash` script into a Windows `.bat` file is not a TeX question, and so off topic for the site.

Answer (score 2):

The following example uses [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) to place a list of numbers (contained within a single-column `tabular`) on the left and/or right of the text block:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,eso-pic,xcolor}

% Specify a verbatim list of numbers (or items) to be on the side of the text block
\newcommand{\numberlist}[1][r]{%
  \begin{tabular}{#1}
    \strut
     1 \\  2 \\  3 \\  4 \\  5 \\  6 \\  7 \\  8 \\  9 \\ 10 \\
    11 \\ 12 \\ 13 \\ 14 \\ 15 \\ 16 \\ 17 \\ 18 \\ 19 \\ 20 \\
    21 \\ 22 \\ 23 \\ 24 \\ 25 \\ 26 \\ 27 \\ 28 \\ 29 \\ 20 \\
    31 \\ 32 \\ 33 \\ 34 \\ 35 \\ 36 \\ 37 \\ 38 \\ 39 \\ 30 \\
    41 \\ 42 \\ 43 \\ 44 \\ 45 \\ 46
  \end{tabular}%
}

\newcommand{\numberlistfont}{%
  \ttfamily\color{black!50}% Font/colour used for number list
}

% Add number list to the ForeGround of every page
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{%
  % Start at the top left of the text block
  \AtTextUpperLeft{%
    \numberlistfont
    % Numbers on left
    \makebox[0pt][r]{\raisebox{-\height}{%
      \numberlist[r]% Print numbers, right-aligned
    }%
    \hspace{50pt}% Space between left numbers and text block
    }%
    \hspace*{\textwidth}% Just to right side of text block
    \hspace{3em}% Space between right numbers and text block
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\raisebox{-\height}{%
      \numberlist[l]% Print numbers, left-aligned
    }}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\sloppy\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

You can adjust the lengths and definitions based on the commented code.