# adjusting line spacing of line numbers within description list

Tags: line-numbering

How can I adjust line spacing of numbers to be in front of text lines within description list:
I couldn't managed to solve the problem with lineno package.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}
\makeatletter

 \newsavebox{\@linebox}
 \savebox{\@linebox}[3em][t]{\parbox[t]{3em}{%
   \@tempcnta\@ne\relax
   \loop{\underline{\scriptsize\the\@tempcnta}}\\
     \advance\@tempcnta by \@ne\ifnum\@tempcnta<48\repeat}}

 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \fancyhead{}
 \fancyfoot{}
 \fancyhead[CO]{\scriptsize How to Count Lines}
 \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\footnotesize\thepage}
%% insert this block within a conditional
 \fancyhead[LE]{\footnotesize\thepage\begin{picture}(0,0)%
      \put(-26,-25){\usebox{\@linebox}}%
      \end{picture}}

 \fancyhead[LO]{%
    \begin{picture}(0,0)%
      \put(-18,-25){\usebox{\@linebox}}%
     \end{picture}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\scriptsize Draft copy}
%% end conditional
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section*{Lorem Ipsum}
{\setstretch{2.8}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
$ALDF$ & Average annual load factor of a DT or HV substation\\
$ALSF$ & Average annual loss factor of a DT or HV substation\\
$APF$ & Average power factor\\
$B$ & Number of all load blocks\\
\end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

[image: numbers are not aligned with text lines.]

I modified the code in (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16012/104963) to ask this question.

Comment: Don't do it that way - use `lineno` package.

Comment: the problem is that lineno does not work for tabular lists e.g. when i make a description list.

Comment: `lineno` works fine for me with description lists.  Please post a complete minimal working example that shows your problem.

Comment: The numbers you get in that format are just for approximately pointing to a line, they aren't supposed to be “real” line numbers. For proof reading they are more than sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lineno` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\linenumbers
\section*{Lorem Ipsum}
\setstretch{1.8}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

This will also work with the standard lists.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}
\linenumbers
\section*{Lorem Ipsum}
\setstretch{1.8}
\begin{description}
    \item[ALDF] Average annual load factor of a DT or HV substation
    \item[ALSF] Average annual loss factor of a DT or HV substation
    \item[APF] Average power factor
    \item[B] Number of all load blocks
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And if you don't like the format of the standard lists you can always customize them.  Here's one way to modify `description` to match the OP example.
Adding this to the preamble of the second example:

```
\renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{\hspace{\labelsep}\makebox[1.27cm][l]{\itshape #1}}
```

gives this:

[image]