# Package incompatibility issue?

Tags: errors, incompatibility, debugging

Why is uncommenting [the two lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16011/27721) in the MWE below throwing an error (see below)?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\title{\textbf{Welcome}}
\author{Alexander}
\date{}

%-------------------------
% \usepackage{lineno}

% \linenumbers
%-------------------------

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Hello, hello}

Hello world.

\end{document}
```

The build log:

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian) 
>   \write18 enabled. entering extended mode (/tmp/gummi_ERIFNY LaTeX2e
>   <2011/06/27> Babel  and hyphenation patterns for english,
>   dumylang, nohyphenation, ng erman, german, swissgerman,
>   ngerman-x-2012-05-30, german-x-2012-05-30, loaded.
>   (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls Document
>   Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
>   (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
>
> ! LaTeX Error: File `lineno.sty' not found.
>
> Type X to quit or  to proceed, or enter new name. (Default
>   extension: sty)
>
> Enter file name:  /tmp/gummi_ERIFNY:10: Emergency stop.  
>             l.10 \linenumbers
>                    ^^M /tmp/gummi_ERIFNY:10:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced! Transcript written on
>   /tmp/gummi_ERIFNY.log.

Comment: Nothing to do with incompatibility. The error says you need to install lineno. Works fine for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple: The package isn’t installed on your system. And your using a quite outdated (4 years old!) distribution. I guess the one shipped with Linux? A current TeX Live can be found at: https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html

Comment: ... as in: read-what-it-says-on-the-tin ;-)