# Problem of line-numbering with gather environment

Tags: equations, line-numbering

I used

```
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers
```

For numbering my lines. I know it has problem with double dollars and for that case I replaced double dollars with `\[\]` and it worked but now I used `\begin{gather*}\end{gather*}` to fit an equation but it caused line-numbering doesn't work for a few lines before this equation. Id there any solution for this?

Comment: I added an empty line before and after the gather environment and it solved the problem. But still if there is any other idea, let me know.

Comment: One possible solution which does not influence spacing is to wrap displayed math in a `linenomath` environment. See e.g. [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43648/82917).

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351984/package-lineno-not-working-well-skips-line-texlive-2016