# Numbering like equations for regular text

Tags: numbering

I want to use have numbering like equations for some regular text. So I am using `equation` environment. I am not writing any mathematics in it, so I'll also use `textrm`.

This is my basic code -

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\noindent Select an\\
Select apple\\
\begin{equation}
\textrm{Merge an \& apple.}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

If I am not wrong the equation comes as a new paragraph as it has an indent and it also leaves some space in between. (Please correct me if I'm wrong.) Basically I don't want this paragraph & I want this change globally. I've already removed the indent by modifying the `mathindent` Is there any way to change something like `mathpar`?

---

Screenshot of the desired output - (but with the equation number)
[image: 1]

---

Code with the help of the solution provided by leandriis -

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\newcounter{mynumber}
\newcommand{\myno}[1]{\refstepcounter{mynumber}(\arabic{mynumber})\label{#1}}

\begin{document}
\noindent Select an\\
Select apple\\
Merge an \& apple. \myno{first}\\

Now merge \eqref{first}
\end{document}
```

This code produced -

[image: 2]

Comment: Could you please explain the purpose of an `equation` environment if there will be no math in it?

Comment: Probably a screenshot of the desired layout (and a bit of background info)  might be useful.

Comment: I want equation numbering & it also helps me to refer them.

Comment: Are you writing an algorithm where a special line need to be numbered and referenced?

Comment: Yes! Exactly that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number every line of pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16010/number-every-line-of-pages)

Comment: Specifically, `\usepackage{lineno}\makeLineNumberRight` and `\linelabel{mylabel}`.  But also, (1) An algorithm is not regular text is definitely not an equation. (2) It would have been very helpful to have mentioned why you want this.

Comment: If you want to typeset algorithms, you may have a look at the `algorithm2e` or `algorithmicx` packages.

Comment: Or `listings` without highlighting (but with line numbers). @Teepeemm it does not really seem like a duplicate of that question? That is for every line in a document, this is just for an environment.

Comment: I want some lines to get numbers, and then I also want to refer them back. It is achieved by the solution provided by @leandriis. Thanks all for your replies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you could use something like the following:

[image]

The blue lines indicate the text width. The red box around the reference is caused by `hyperref`.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newcounter{mynumber}
\newcommand{\myno}[1]{\refstepcounter{mynumber}(\arabic{mynumber})\label{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}Xr@{}}
Select an \\
Select apple \\
Merge an \& apple. & \myno{label}\\
\end{tabularx}

Here comes a reference: \ref{label}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes this is a good solution for me. Actually the tabular package is not needed for my purpose, but your definitions helped me. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hey! I am sorry, I said this worked for me, but I want the number to come on the extreme right of the page **as it comes in the equation environment.** Please tell me how to do it.

Comment: @Niranjan: As you can see from my screenshot, the numbers are in fact already at the right margin. This is due to me using `tabularx`. If you insist on not using a table, you probably can use something like `Merge an \& apple. \hfill \myno{label}` instead.

Comment: Oh yes. Thanks!

Comment: I just added `hfill` to the command suggested by you like this. `\newcommand{\myno}[1]{\hfill\refstepcounter{mynumber}(\arabic{mynumber})\label{#1}}` & it produced what I wanted globally :)

Answer (score 5):

I guess you want something like this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-3]
\begin{flalign}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
Select an\\
Select apple\\
Merge an \& apple.
\end{tabular}&&\label{whatever}
\end{flalign}
\lipsum*[2][1-3]

Reference to the thing above is \ref{whatever}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this is probably not what I want, because I also want to refer them. Answer provided by @leandriis works fine for me.

Comment: @Niranjan You just add `\label{whatever}` outside the `tabular` and use `\ref{whatever}`. I added it.

Comment: Yes please see the edit. I've changed the question as I just realized `equation` was not a right choice.