# Cross referencing to any reference counter without adding labels

Tags: cross-referencing, labels

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/510797/174620) answer provided a great solution for creating a new reference counter. I have a further idea to refer to a particular point without putting `label` or `ref` manually. This is done in package `linguex` for a different purpose. Let's see this code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{linguex}
\newcounter{mynumber}
\newcommand{\myno}[1]{\hfill\refstepcounter{mynumber}(\arabic{mynumber})\label{#1}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\ex. This is one example.

\lipsum[1]
\ex. This is another example.

Example \LLast illustrates abc and \Last illustrates xyz.

\section{New section}
This is my first theorem. \myno{first}\\
This is my second theorem. \myno{}\\
By \eqref{first} it is evident that bla bla bla.\\
By \eqref{} it is evident that bla bla bla.\\
\end{document}
```

This code will produce -

[image: 1]

Now as the `linguex` package provides me commands like `\Last`, `\LLast` I want them to be for these new ref-counters. Is it possible?

---

This is a pseudo code made by me. It looks almost the same, but has two additional commands which should end-up in referring to the theorem-numbers in an automated way. The expected output is exactly the same like the screenshot attached.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{linguex}
\newcounter{mynumber}
\newcommand{\myno}{\hfill\refstepcounter{mynumber}(\arabic{mynumber})}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    \ex. This is one example.

    \lipsum[1]
    \ex. This is another example.

    Example \LLast illustrates abc and \Last illustrates xyz.

    \section{New section}
    This is my first theorem. \myno\\ % Note that I have no compulsory label argument here. It is automatically labelled.
    This is my second theorem. \myno\\
    By \NewLast it is evident that bla bla bla.\\ % Here the labels are referred.
    By \NewLLast it is evident that bla bla bla.\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: your question is not very clear about where you want lablels, what input do you want to use, and what output do you want it to generate?

Comment: Changing the counter name used in the custom defined `\myno` to the counter name used in `linguex` could at a first glance give the desired result: `\newcommand{\myno}[1]{\refstepcounter{ExNo}(\arabic{ExNo})\label{#1}}`.

Comment: you could use  `\themynumber` as the equivalent to `\last` to get the last used number, is that what you need?

Comment: Please see the edit. Sorry for not being very clear before.

Comment: so you just want `\def\NewLast{\the\value{mynumber}}` and `\def\NewLLast{\the\numexpr\value{mynumber}-1\relax}` ?

Comment: Solved my problem :) Thanks!

Comment: I want to break this numbering somewhere & start new. How should I define a command? Numbering should start from one after my command.