# Lines Numbers with mdframed

Tags: mdframed, line-numbering

Am looking for an elegant way to include line numbers in my `mdframed` documents. Unfortunately, the following produces a 85 page docuement with `\linenumbers` (either *before* or *after* the `\begin{mdframed}`. Document is only 4 pages without the `\linenumbers`.

### References:

- Am ok with a post processing solution, but was not able to get Jake's solution from [Add page and line numbers to a pdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18760/add-page-and-line-numbers-to-a-pdf) to work. And yes I know that saying "it doesn't work" does not help to figure out what the problem is -- might post a separate question, but thought that using `lineno` package would be easier.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}\linenumbers
    \lipsum
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [fill=yellow!25] (0,0) rectangle (3,4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \lipsum
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44443/mdframed-with-tikz-method-putting-line-numbers-outside-of-frame) of any help?

Comment: @Jubobs: Yeah I saw that question, but that seems more of a method of manually adding line numbers. I need an automated solution.

Comment: Have you tried recycling some code for line numbering from the `algorithm2e` package?

Comment: @Jubobs: No have not, but sure if that would work, as the solution I need needs to work with TeX's line breaking algorithm, and I think those packages have their own.

Comment: The issue isn't related to `mdframed`. A similar question with `minipage` can be found here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103163/line-numbering-with-lineno-within-minipage

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13515/how-to-add-paragraph-line-number-in-right-margin

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Yep that solution mostly works for me. Close this as a dupe then?

Comment: I marked as duplicated.