# Problem with elsarticle and lineno

Tags: header-footer, line-numbering, elsarticle

I am using the `elsarticle` class in order to typeset a preprint of an article I am writing.

I wanted to add line numbering in order to make the revision easier, so I included the `lineno` package.

This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[preprint,review]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% ADDING LINENUMBERS FOR REVIEWING:
\usepackage{lineno}
    \linenumbers

\journal{The Name Of The Journal}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{The Tile Of The Article}

\author[]{Name1 Surname1\corref{cor1}}
\ead{surname1@email.ok}
\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author. Tel.: WHATEVER; Fax: WHATEVER.}
\author[]{Name2 Surname2}
\ead{surname2@email.ok}
\author[]{Name2 Surname3}
\ead{surname3@email.ok}
\address{Research Structure Name, University Name, Full Postal Address.}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[31]
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
Keyword1; Keyword2; Keyword3; Keyword4; Keyword5
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}


\section{Introduction and background}

\subsection{Introduction}

\lipsum[1-5]

\subsection{Background}

\lipsum[6-15]

\subsection{Aims and scope}

\lipsum[16-20]

\section{Conclusions}

\lipsum[21-30]

\section*{Acknowledgements}

Thanks to all!

\end{document}
```

And this is what I get (1st page, see bottom):

[image: Elsarticle With Lineno]

The normal result when removing these two lines in the tex document:

```
\usepackage{lineno}
    \linenumbers
```

is the following (see the bottom):

[image: Elsarticle Without Lineno]

So, author information is overlaped with the bottom line *"Preprint sumbitted to [...]"*. How can I fix this issue??

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I am answering my own question.

I managed to solve this issue by just moving the `\linenumbers` sentence to the beginning of the main text —that is:

```
\documentclass[preprint,review]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% ADDING LINENUMBERS FOR REVIEWING:
\usepackage{lineno}
%    \linenumbers   <---- NOT HERE !!!

\journal{The Name Of The Journal}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{\begin{linenumbers}The Tile Of The Article\end{linenumbers}}


\author[]{Name1 Surname1\corref{cor1}}
\ead{surname1@email.ok}
\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author. Tel.: WHATEVER; Fax: WHATEVER.}
\author[]{Name2 Surname2}
\ead{surname2@email.ok}
\author[]{Name2 Surname3}
\ead{surname3@email.ok}
\address{Research Structure Name, University Name, Full Postal Address.}



\begin{abstract}

\lipsum[31]

\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
Keyword1; Keyword2; Keyword3; Keyword4; Keyword5
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

\linenumbers  %% <---- BUT HERE !

\section{Introduction and background}

\subsection{Introduction}

\lipsum[1-5]

\subsection{Background}

\lipsum[6-15]

\subsection{Aims and scope}

\lipsum[16-20]

\section{Conclusions}

\lipsum[21-30]

\section*{Acknowledgements}

Thanks to all!

\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image: MWE result]

It is a little bit strange that the title line gets actually numbered, but it is OK for me that the abstract is not numbered, after reading the answer by @Loop-Space to a similar question regarding `lineno`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11406/8283, where he points out that `lineno` is intended to number only the main text.

It's not perfect, but it is OK for me.

Answer (score 7):

An analysis of the problem would be quite time consuming, because `lineno` does many hacks and `elsarticle` too.

A simple workaround is to add `\enlargethispage{-2\baselineskip}` after `\end{frontmatter}`. In order to have this in the same place with `\usepackage{lineno}` so that you can easily remove it when the final version is submitted is

```
% ADDING LINENUMBERS FOR REVIEWING:
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\endfrontmatter{\enlargethispage{-2\baselineskip}}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Moving the `\linenumbers` command to the beginning of the main text is now an official advice from the company that provides technical support for this style file: [FAQ - `elsarticle.cls`](http://support.river-valley.com/wiki/index.php?title=FAQ_-_elsarticle.cls) (see p.13 of the "Preamble and Front matter section")