# elsarticle document class: front matter parts are written one over another

Tags: elsarticle, front-matter, journal-publishing, journal

We are about to submit a paper to Elsevier, but it seems that something is wrong (or we are doing it wrong) in the front matter. This is the code bit:

```
\author[FFNS]{One Author\corref{mycorrespondingauthor}}

\cortext[mycorrespondingauthor]{Correspondence should be addressed
to One Author, Laboratory for Something, Faculty of
Anotherthing, University of Thirdthing. Email: {\tt one.author@e.mail}}
```

And this is how it looks in pdf:

[image]

What is going on here?

---

Thanks to both [darthbith](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/32374/darthbith) and [jean-sébastien-gosselin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/72419/jean-s%C3%A9bastien-gosselin) (but especially darthbith who kindly taught me some manners [ ;-) ]), I patiently made a minimal example, and then figured out what seems to be the problem. To explain the details, I am attaching two examples: one with short abstract ([short tex](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_UCSWfE-FjeYmphSXlIN3VnREU&authuser=0);[short pdf](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_UCSWfE-Fjec2xCblp4X0xINkU&authuser=0)) and one with long abstract that spreads over the front and first page ([long tex](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_UCSWfE-FjeVVZjZUxlYU9vcnc&authuser=0); [long pdf](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_UCSWfE-FjeakMyOVpSNlNRQzA&authuser=0)).

In brief, in shortAbs I added \newpage at the beginning of the body, and that made the difference -- neat, readable compilation. (Without \newpage pdf will still be compiled with that ugly error!) In longAbs, since abstract is over two pages, I did not figure out how to fix this.

Now, I can ask better questions, I suppose: if the abstract is long and you use elsarticle document class, how to make correspondence note and a note about journal and the date not to overlap?

Thanks!

Comment: Please make your code compilable by completing it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem. Also, it's not necessary to sign your questions (as [there is already a box with your username below it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures)). Good question!

Comment: @striatum Tested your code. Everything seems ok in my environment. So this behaviour is due to something else.

Comment: @striatum Thanks for posting the example code! Can you edit it into your question, so that we don't have to download an unknown (possibly insecure) file from an external website? Also, think of the future readers of this question - they won't be able to access that file if you remove it from the source. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

After great discussion with [darthbith](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/32374/darthbith) and [jean-sébastien-gosselin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/72419/jean-s%C3%A9bastien-gosselin), I think that we figured out what caused the problem. For sure that is the lineno package linenumbers. In addition, the abstract length could interfere as well. Following [darthbith](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/32374/darthbith) suggestions/requests, I am posting two minimal examples, so that anyone can replicate critical behavior:

**(1) SHORT ABSTRACT:**

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabulary}

\journal{Some Journal}

%-- Line numbering
\pagewiselinenumbers
\modulolinenumbers[2]

%-- Hyperreferencing
\usepackage[bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=true,
    bookmarksopenlevel=2,breaklinks=true,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,
    colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=blue]
    {hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfstartview={XYZ null null 1}}

%-- Float definition
\renewcommand\floatpagefraction{.9}
\renewcommand\topfraction{.9}
\renewcommand\bottomfraction{.9}
\renewcommand\textfraction{.1}   
\setcounter{totalnumber}{50}
\setcounter{topnumber}{50}
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{50}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Elsevier bibliography styles
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% To change the style, put a % in front of the second line of the current style and
%% remove the % from the second line of the style you would like to use.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% Numbered
%\bibliographystyle{model1-num-names}

%% Numbered without titles
%\bibliographystyle{model1a-num-names}

%% Harvard
%\bibliographystyle{model2-names.bst}\biboptions{authoryear}

%% Vancouver numbered
%\usepackage{numcompress}\bibliographystyle{model3-num-names}

%% Vancouver name/year
%\usepackage{numcompress}\bibliographystyle{model4-names}\biboptions{authoryear}

%% APA style
%\bibliographystyle{model5-names}\biboptions{authoryear}

%% AMA style
%\usepackage{numcompress}\bibliographystyle{model6-num-names}

%% `Elsevier LaTeX' style
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Is this a boring title? \protect\\
    The effect of boring titles on the boresommness}

\author[X]{One Author\corref{mycorrespondingauthor}}

\cortext[mycorrespondingauthor]{Correspondence should be addressed
to One Author, Laboratory for Something, Faculty of
Anotherthing, University of Thirdthing. Email: {\tt one.author@e.mail}}

\author[X,Y]{Second Author}

\address[X]{University of Third Thing}
\address[Y]{Awe Some University of Awesomeness}

\begin{abstract}
{\bf Groucho Marx:} Each morning when I open my eyes I say to myself: I, not
events, have the power to make me happy or unhappy today. I can choose which it
shall be. Yesterday is dead, tomorrow hasn't arrived yet. I have just one day,
today, and I'm going to be happy in it. {\bf Viktor E. Frankl:} We who lived in
concentration camps can remember the men who walked through the huts comforting
others, giving away their last piece of bread. They may have been few in
number, but they offer sufficient proof that everything can be taken from a man
but one thing: the last of the human freedoms -- to choose one's attitude in
any given set of circumstances, to choose one's own way. {\bf Mark Twain:}
Twenty years from now you will be more disappointed by the things you didn't do
than by the ones you did. So throw off the bowlines, Sail away from the safe
harbor. Catch the trade winds in your sails. Explore. Dream. \\
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
    one \sep two \sep three \sep four \sep five
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

\newpage

\linenumbers

\section{Introduction}

BLAH BLAH BLAH

\section*{Acknowledgements}

\noindent
This research was funded by the Ministry of Time and Money Waste of the Republic of Rich People (grants ON179006 and ON179033), and is partially based on F. A's PhD thesis carried out at the
University of Thirdthing. We thank all \ldots

\end{document}
```

**(2) LONG ABSTRACT:**

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabulary}

\journal{Some Journal}

%-- Line numbering
\pagewiselinenumbers
\modulolinenumbers[2]

%-- Hyperreferencing
\usepackage[bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=true,
    bookmarksopenlevel=2,breaklinks=true,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,
    colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=blue]
    {hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfstartview={XYZ null null 1}}

%-- Float definition
\renewcommand\floatpagefraction{.9}
\renewcommand\topfraction{.9}
\renewcommand\bottomfraction{.9}
\renewcommand\textfraction{.1}   
\setcounter{totalnumber}{50}
\setcounter{topnumber}{50}
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{50}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Elsevier bibliography styles
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% To change the style, put a % in front of the second line of the current style and
%% remove the % from the second line of the style you would like to use.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% Numbered
%\bibliographystyle{model1-num-names}

%% Numbered without titles
%\bibliographystyle{model1a-num-names}

%% Harvard
%\bibliographystyle{model2-names.bst}\biboptions{authoryear}

%% Vancouver numbered
%\usepackage{numcompress}\bibliographystyle{model3-num-names}

%% Vancouver name/year
%\usepackage{numcompress}\bibliographystyle{model4-names}\biboptions{authoryear}

%% APA style
%\bibliographystyle{model5-names}\biboptions{authoryear}

%% AMA style
%\usepackage{numcompress}\bibliographystyle{model6-num-names}

%% `Elsevier LaTeX' style
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Is this a boring title? \protect\\
    The effect of boring titles on the boresommness}

\author[X]{One Author\corref{mycorrespondingauthor}}

\cortext[mycorrespondingauthor]{Correspondence should be addressed
to One Author, Laboratory for Something, Faculty of
Anotherthing, University of Thirdthing. Email: {\tt one.author@e.mail}}

\author[X,Y]{Second Author}

\address[X]{University of Third Thing}
\address[Y]{Awe Some University of Awesomeness}

\begin{abstract}
{\bf Groucho Marx:} Each morning when I open my eyes I say to myself: I, not
events, have the power to make me happy or unhappy today. I can choose which it
shall be. Yesterday is dead, tomorrow hasn't arrived yet. I have just one day,
today, and I'm going to be happy in it. {\bf Viktor E. Frankl:} We who lived in
concentration camps can remember the men who walked through the huts comforting
others, giving away their last piece of bread. They may have been few in
number, but they offer sufficient proof that everything can be taken from a man
but one thing: the last of the human freedoms -- to choose one's attitude in
any given set of circumstances, to choose one's own way. {\bf Mark Twain:}
Twenty years from now you will be more disappointed by the things you didn't do
than by the ones you did. So throw off the bowlines, Sail away from the safe
harbor. Catch the trade winds in your sails. Explore. Dream. {\bf Johann
Wolfgang von Goethe:} All truly wise thoughts have been thought already
thousands of times; but to make them truly ours, we must think them over again
honestly, till they take root in our personal experience. {\bf John Eliot:}
History shows us that the people who end up changing the world -- the great
political, social, scientific, technological, artistic, even sports
revolutionaries -- are always nuts, until they are right, and then they are
geniuses. {\bf Calvin Coolidge:} Nothing in the world can take the place of
persistence. Talent will not; nothing is more common than unsuccessful men with
talent. Genius will not; unrewarded genius is almost a proverb. Education will
not; the world is full of educated derelicts. Persistence and determination are
omnipotent. The slogan ``press on'' has solved and always will solve
the problems of the human race. {\bf Alfred D'Souza:} For a long time it had
seemed to me that life was about to begin -- real life. But there was always
some obstacle in the way, something to be gotten through first, some unfinished
business, time still to be served, a debt to be paid. Then life would begin. At
last it dawned on me that these obstacles were my life. {\bf Louise L Hay:} You
are not here to please other people or to live your lives their way. You can
only live it your own way and walk your own pathway. You have come to fulfill
yourself and express love on the deepest level. You are here to learn and grow.
When you leave the planet... the only thing you take is your capacity to love!
{\bf Napoleon Hill:} The strongest oak of the forest is not the one that is
protected from the storm and hidden from the sun. It's the one that stands in
the open where it is compelled to struggle for its existence against the winds
and rains and the scorching sun. \\
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
    one \sep two \sep three \sep four \sep five
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

\linenumbers

\section{Introduction}

BLAH BLAH BLAH

\section*{Acknowledgements}

\noindent
This research was funded by the Ministry of Time and Money Waste of the Republic of Rich People (grants ON179006 and ON179033), and is partially based on F. A's PhD thesis carried out at the
University of Thirdthing. We thank all \ldots

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to originate from the use of `linenumbers` in the `abstract` environment as discussed here: [Problem with elsarticle and lineno](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192085/problem-with-elsarticle-and-lineno). A workaround would be to move the `linenumbers` command to the main body of the article such as in this MWE:

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lipsum} % only for filler text
\usepackage{lineno}
\modulolinenumbers[2]

\journal{Some Journal}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frontmatter}

        \title{Some Title}

        \author[FFNS]{One Author\corref{mycorrespondingauthor}}

        \cortext[mycorrespondingauthor]{Correspondence should be addressed
        to One Author, Laboratory for Something, Faculty of
        Anotherthing, University of Thirdthing. Email: {\tt one.author@e.mail}}

        \begin{abstract}            
            \lipsum[1-3] % filler text          
        \end{abstract}

    \end{frontmatter}

    \pagewiselinenumbers
    \lipsum[1-2] % filler text

\end{document}
```

Which yields a 2-pages article with the abstract spilling on 2 pages, without the overlapping text in the footer note. The lines of the abstract won't be numbered though.

[image]