# Elsarticle problem - overlapping footer when using lineno

Tags: header-footer, elsarticle, lineno

I am having issues with the `elsarticle` latex template. My abstract is long (over 2 pages due to spacing and font size which is designated by the journal), and when I use `lineno` the footer becomes crowded (please see image).

This is similar to the question which can be found here, and I have looked through the answers: [Problem with elsarticle and lineno](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192085/problem-with-elsarticle-and-lineno?newreg=08fd87a186844dc09473c21d11b825a9)

However, using `\enlargethispage{-2\baselineskip}` after `\end{frontmatter}` does not work in this situation as the abstract is over 2 pages (though I would like to be able to apply `\enlargethispage{}` for the first page. However, I do need line numbers even for my absrerct due to the specific journal requirements.

Is there any way to have line numbers for the abstract over 2 pages and yet still not have a crowded footer?

Example code here

```
\documentclass[preprint,review]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% ADDING LINENUMBERS FOR REVIEWING:
\usepackage{lineno}
    \linenumbers

\journal{The Name Of The Journal}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{The Tile Of The Article}

\author[]{Name1 Surname1\corref{cor1}}
\ead{surname1@email.ok}
\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author. Tel.: WHATEVER; Fax: WHATEVER.}
\author[]{Name2 Surname2}
\ead{surname2@email.ok}
\author[]{Name2 Surname3}
\ead{surname3@email.ok}
\address{Research Structure Name, University Name, Full Postal Address.}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
Keyword1; Keyword2; Keyword3; Keyword4; Keyword5
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}


\section{Introduction and background}

\subsection{Introduction}

\lipsum[1-5]

\subsection{Background}

\lipsum[6-15]

\subsection{Aims and scope}

\lipsum[16-20]

\section{Conclusions}

\lipsum[21-30]

\section*{Acknowledgements}

Thanks to all!

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Move the `\linenumbers` after the frontmatter as [suggested by OP](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193220/224613) in the [thread you linked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192085/problem-with-elsarticle-and-lineno?newreg=08fd87a186844dc09473c21d11b825a9). It worked for me!

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the answer to be worded as an answer.