# Adding line numbers to abstract for revtex 4-1

Tags: revtex

I have a latex document in revtex 4-1. I have added the `linenumbers` option in the preamble, and everything (even the title) has line numbers except for the abstract. How do I add line numbers to the abstract?

Here's what I have:

```
\documentclass[
    pre,
    twocolumn,
    % twoside,
    byrevtex,
    superscriptaddress,
    floatfix,
    nofootinbib,
    longbibliography,
    linenumbers
]{revtex4-1}

\begin{document}

\title{\protect
Sample title
}


\begin{abstract}
test

several

lines
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Test}
Line 1

Line 2

\clearpage

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer thanks to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/277545/168596:

```
\begin{abstract}
% add line numbers to the abstract
\begin{linenumbers}
test

several

lines
\end{linenumbers}
\end{abstract}

\nolinenumbers % removes line number from the title
\maketitle

\linenumbers
% insert rest of document here
```

Comment: Does this require the `linenumbers` class option to be used?  If not is the `\nolinenumbers` necessary if the `linenumbers` class option is omitted?

Comment: I haven't checked. I do use `linenumbers` in the class option though.